# Adding a drop down in itemtemplate and populating value dynamically

Tags: c#, .net, asp.net

I have an item template in a GridView and I want to create a dropdown for each row and bind it to a value retrieved from the database.. but I am not sure how to do this.. this is what i have so far.. but not sure where to put the code to populate the drop down per row..

```
 <ItemTemplate>
     <asp:DropDownList runat="server" ID="ddlMyQuantity" SelectedValue='<%# 
       (DataBinder.Eval(Container.DataItem,"Quantity")) %>'>
     </asp:DropDownList>
  </ItemTemplate>
```

and in code behind, not sure how to or where to put this so that it is created on every row..

```
 public void BindMyQuantity()
    {
        for (int i = 1; i < 15; i++)
        {
            ddlMyQuantity.Items.Add(i.ToString());
        }
    }
```

Also i am not sure if i can do that, but the code is not complaining.. adding SelectedValue in the asp declaration

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use [`OnRowDataBound`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.webcontrols.gridview.onrowdatabound.aspx) to dynamically bind your dropdown:

```
protected void GridView_RowDataBound(Object sender, GridViewRowEventArgs e)
{
  if(e.Row.RowType == DataControlRowType.DataRow)
  {
     var dropdownList = (DropDownList)e.Row.FindControl("ddlMyQuantity");
     for (int i = 1; i < 15; i++)
     {
        dropdownList.Items.Add(i.ToString());
     }
     dropdownList.SelectedValue = 
           Convert.ToString(DataBinder.Eval(e.Row.DataItem, "Quantity"));
  }
}
```

Add binding:

```
<asp:GridView ... OnRowDataBound="GridView_RowDataBound">
    ...
</asp:GridView>
```

Comment: Great, how about that last question I added at the end? thank you very much

Comment: Yes that's perfectly valid, although you may hit an issue if the DropDownList is not bound in time for the SelectedValue binding. It might be safer to do this in your OnRowDataBound event.

Comment: Question I am trying to bind it.. but it is still comming back blank.. any ideas why?

Comment: What's blank, the Dropdown or selected value?

Comment: the drop down is blank.. and then i need to figure out how to do the selected value because it finally complained about it

Comment: Did you wire up the event, is it declared as protected, is it getting called? I'll update with SelectedValue example, I think it's binding to early.

Comment: Oh yes it was because of the protection level thank you very much

Answer (score 0):

As per my knowledge, the best option would be to write this code in "RowDataBound" event of the Grid. See sample code below.

```
   protected void GridView_RowDataBound(..)
   {
       if (e.Row.RowType.Equals(DataControlRowType.DataRow))
        {
            DropDownList ddl = e.Row.FindControl("ddlMyQuantity") as DropDownList;

            if (ddl != null)
            {
               for (int i = 1; i < 15; i++)
               {
                   ddl.Items.Add(i.ToString());
               }
            }
        }
   }
```

In the aspx page, provide this

```
   <ItemTemplate>        
        <asp:DropDownList runat="server" ID="ddlMyQuantity"></asp:DropDownList> 
   </ItemTemplate>
```

Hope this Helps!!

Answer (score 0):

```
<asp:TemplateField HeaderText="Type Cargo" HeaderStyle-HorizontalAlign="Center" ItemStyle-Width="10%" ItemStyle-HorizontalAlign="Center"> 
                <ItemTemplate>
                    <asp:DropDownList ID="DropDownList1" runat="server" DataValueField="DESCRIPTION"></asp:DropDownList>

                </ItemTemplate>
            </asp:TemplateField>
```

Code Behind will look like this...

```
Dim rowId As DropDownList

        For i As Integer = 0 To gridView1.Rows.Count - 1

            Dim gridrow As GridViewRow = gridView1.Rows(i)

            rowId = DirectCast(gridrow.FindControl("DropDownList1"), DropDownList)
            Dim dt As DataTable = Get_List()
            rowId.DataSource = dt
            rowId.DataBind()

        Next
```

Get_List is a Function that returns a DataTable